# How to sort two DataFrame simultaneously

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have one dataframe stored the numeric data and the other dataframe is the category. But, I want to sort two dataframe at the same time.

Each entry in df_A can be mapped to df_B. As df_A stores numeric data while as df_B stored its category. So, eventually, I want to reconstruct a new dataframe to have a dataframe to store the numeric data by each category. What I can think about is sort df_A and df_B simultaneously and then rename df_A's index.

```
>>print (df_A)
    26   27   28   33
3  0.9  1.0  0.4  0.0
4  1.0  0.8  1.0  0.4
5  0.9  1.0  1.0  0.9

>>print (df_B)
   26  27  28  33
3  BL  LP  PE  BL
4  PE  BL  LP  PE
5  LP  PE  BL  LP
```

Expected outcome:

```
    26    27   28  33
BL  0.9  0.8  1.0  0.0  
PE  1.0  1.0  0.4  0.8 
LP  0.9  1.0  1.0  0.9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the columns of first dataframe based on the column of second where the second is mapped with integers and then argsort returns the index position of the values. Query the first values in that order.

```
>>> order = {'BL': 0, 'PE': 1, 'LP': 2}
>>> df_A.apply(lambda x: list(x.iloc[df_B[x.name].map(order).argsort()]))
    26   27   28   33
3  0.9  0.8  1.0  0.0
4  1.0  1.0  0.4  0.4
5  0.9  1.0  1.0  0.9

>>> df.index = order.keys()
>>> df
     26   27   28   33
BL  0.9  0.8  1.0  0.0
PE  1.0  1.0  0.4  0.4
LP  0.9  1.0  1.0  0.9
```